# Is there a way to white list countries that can use a Messenger bot?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, country

My bot will display content that are available on a specific list of countries.
So I would like to restrict the usage of my Messenger Bot to those countries.
Any ideas ? I can restrict the fan page but if usere visit my bot from m.me links they can have access.

Comment: Not sure if that helps in this instance, but try the country restriction setting in the app dashboard (Settings -> Advanced)

Comment: You can also use the user profile API to get the user's locale and then return a default message if the user isn't in one of the locales you support:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile